# Discord target user ID

Tags: python, bots, discord

I was wondering if there was a way to convert someones username to their ID requested upon a different user. Basically when a user requests for someone elses ID, they type in their name and it returns the specified users ID.

I'm totally new to python and stackoverflow, so any help is very helpful Thank You.

EDIT: Since I am creating individual user files for each user I use a users ID to name them, now I just need something that will convert someones username into their ID.

Comment: Please add more information about your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before posting a question, it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you are stuck on something *specific*, include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you can save the username in dict in python so basically you would create a dictionary with a username as key i.e.

```
desc={"Ali":123,"Mathew" :1234}
```

so print desc["Mathew"]; would print 1234 which is id of Mathew